# How to apply regex in tag name when filtering adb logcat in bash

Tags: android, logging, kotlin, adb, logcat

I wonder if there is any way to apply a regular expression on to `tag names` while filtering `adb logcat` logs. I can use `grep` pipe but it applies on the whole text rather only tag names. I want to apply regex in tag names only. For example,

```
$ adb logcat -v tag | grep MyData*
```

produces,

```
D/MyActivity: calling MyDataManager
D/MyDataManager: data1 inserted
D/MyDataWorker: data1 inserted
```

But my expected output is,

```
D/MyDataManager: data1 inserted
D/MyDataWorker: data1 inserted
```

How to do that?

Comment: Could you just do `grep -e "./MyData"`?

Comment: This will include anything that starts with /MyData in log message as well. Is there any support from adb side?

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt support for grep with regexp on `tag` from `adb logcat` . But Below worked for me to match all logs which has tag starts with `Activ`.

```
adb shell logcat | grep -P "^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+Activ"
```

`-P` for perl like regexp support.
Make pattern with `\s whitespace` and `\S non whitespace` chars until you reach the `tag`. 
For Example in below log, it starts with non whitespace '07-08' which will match with first `\S+` in pattern. similarly for rest of the pattern.

> 07-08 17:13:00.042  1677  1708 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 475

Comment: Could you explain how this pattern works? I am even tired of counting the number of chars.

Comment: I have edited answer. Sorry I didn't realize i had different version of grep in my device. But modified answer would work for your case.